# how to save Image data from FirebaseStorage to database and retrieve it using CircleAvatar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

> Hi  im trying to insert my the image  data from firebase storage into my database however all the idea i have didn't work by the way in using Floor for my database any suggestion or idea will be well appreciated.

**Here is my code for get the image from firebase Storage the image to database**

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  imgString = Utility.base64String(image.readAsBytesSync()); //here where i get the image
  setState(() {
    _image = image;
    print('Image Path $_image');
  });
}
Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
  String fileName = Path.basename(_image.path);
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
      .child(fileName);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
  StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
 // setState(() {
    print("Profile Picture uploaded");
   //  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Profile Picture Uploaded')));
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'New Data was Uploaded',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM);
 // });
}
```

**Here my code for saving the image data to database**

```
 insertData() async {
if(widget.firstnameController.text.isNotEmpty && widget.lastnameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
    widget.contactnumberController.text.isNotEmpty && widget.birthdayController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var addContacts = ContactObject(
      firstname: widget.firstnameController.value.text,
      lastname: widget.lastnameController.value.text,
      birthday: widget.birthdayController.value.text,
      contactnumber: int.parse(widget.contactnumberController.value.text),
      profilepicture: Utility.imageFromBase64String(imgString).toString()); //Here is the image data
  await _contactsDao.insertContact(addContacts);
} else {
  print('ERROR');
}
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Contactscreen()));
});
```

}

**Here my code where i covert it base64 Data**

```
    class Utility {

  static Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return Image.memory(
      base64Decode(base64String),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  }

  static Uint8List dataFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return base64Decode(base64String);
  }

  static String base64String(Uint8List data) {
    return base64Encode(data);
  }
}
```

**Here where i call/display the image data to circleAvatar**

```
                   CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: new SizedBox(
                            // width: 180.0,
                            // height: 180.0,
                            child: Image.file(File('${listContact[index].profilepicture}'),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

H**ere is the Exception error**

```
Cannot open file, path = 'Image(image: MemoryImage(Uint8List#1a942, scale: 1.0), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, fit: fill, alignment: center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `uploadPic` function to this:

```
Future getImage() async {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {
    _image = image;
    print('Image Path $_image');
  });
}

 static Future<String> uploadPic(String path) async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(File(path));
    var url = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
```

Above function will take path of image and then return it's url which you can insert into the database. You can easily show image from your database now because you have have it's url stored.

In insert data function you need to call uploadPic again to upload the image and return its url to store in `profilePicture` key.

```
insertData() async {
    if (widget.firstnameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        widget.lastnameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        widget.contactnumberController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        widget.birthdayController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var addContacts = ContactObject(
          firstname: widget.firstnameController.value.text,
          lastname: widget.lastnameController.value.text,
          birthday: widget.birthdayController.value.text,
          contactnumber: int.parse(widget.contactnumberController.value.text),
          // pass path of image in this function. for ex (if image is stored in map use image.values.first (it will return path)
          profilepicture: await uploadPic(_image.path)
      ); //Here is the image data
      await _contactsDao.insertContact(addContacts);
    } else {
      print('ERROR');
    }
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Contactscreen()));
    });
  }
```

Lastly you can show image from database easily in Image.network because you have its url

```
            CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: new SizedBox(
                          // width: 180.0,
                          // height: 180.0,
                          child: 
                    Image.network(listContact[index].profilepicture,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

**Here is the result!**

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: hi @Haroon Thanks for the response i will try this.

Comment: hi @Haroon when i try your idea got this Exceptiion  `Failed assertion: line 62 pos 12: 'file.existsSync()': is not true.` Thank you

Comment: Can you please share your code again or capture an image of it and share.. Seems like image you are trying to upload doesnt exist ..most probably you arent passing the correct path in uploadPic function. Try printing path in the function to see if this is an error

Comment: hi @haroom i guess the Exception is that `uploadPic` doesn't get the image data from image picker on `getImage()` please take a look Thank you

Comment: hi @haroon please take a look on my edited post Thank you.

Comment: modified the code. getImage() function returns a File type that we are storing in _image variable. in uploadPic function I have now passed _image.path

Comment: hi @haroon Thank you so much for you effort really appreciated God bless and you family , please take a look of the screen shot :)